# Not a Valid Choice for Dynamic Select Field WTFORMS

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I currently am creating a dynamic select field using WTFORMS, however it never submits and fails the validation with the following error.

```
Not a valid choice
```

My Field is created like this:

```
area = SelectField()
```

and in the view, i am grabbing the options from the db like so:

```
form = MytestForm()
form.area.choices = [(a.id, a.name) for a in Area.objects.all()]
```

It works however if i create static options.

Comment: There a known issue related to this question see e.g. https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/434 but there are more. It's confusing

Answer (score 117, accepted):

My guess is that `Area.id` is a `int` - when data comes back from the client it is treated as a *string* by WTForms unless a callable is passed to the `coerce` keyword argument of the [`wtforms.fields.SelectField`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=fields.selectfield#wtforms.fields.SelectField) constructor:

```
area = SelectField(coerce=int)
```

Alternately, if you are using SQLAlchemy you could use [`wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ext.html?highlight=wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.queryselectfield#wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField) ([`wtforms_sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms-sqlalchemy) if you are using WTForms 3+):

```
area = QuerySelectField(query_factory=Area.objects.all,
                            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
                            get_label=lambda a: a.name)
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the response. However i am using mongodb, so the id is actually a string.

Comment: Thanks it was the coerce issue, WTFORMS was defaulting to converting to unicode, however the actual object is a MongoDB Object ID type. so i changed the coerce to create an ObjectID instance, and it validates now.

Comment: coerce=int fixed it for me.

Specifically, my problem was that my choices values happened to be integers 0 and 1. 

My guess is that wtforms was interpreting this as False and True.
However, my model wants an int.

class Abc(Base):
    foo = Column(Integer)

class AbcView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'foo': SelectField,
    }
    form_args = {
        'foo': {
            'choices': [ (0, 'unknown'), (1, 'defcon 1') ],
            'coerce': int
         }
    }

Comment: Dear @SeanVieira thank you very much for wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField. It saved me a lifetime :)

Comment: coerce=int - worked for me, but for other case. thank you!

Comment: QuerySelectField() is not working form me. If I use SelectField add coerce=int it works..

Comment: That's because the latest version (3.0) removes the extension from the main package and makes it a separate package. https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms-sqlalchemy

Comment: If you include a blank option, then you can use something like this: `coerce=lambda value: '' if value == '' else int(value)` to avoid `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you can solve it without QuerySelectField.

Here is how I did:

```
years = [(str(y), y) for y in reversed(range(1950, 2013))]
years.insert(0, ('','year'))
year = wt.SelectField(choices=years)
```

Answer (score 6):

[a 3.01 Pullrequest](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/493/commits/a15e84d971048b7004b855b059b41984af25af30) adds the necessary argument:

```py
 validate_choice=True
```

To switch off the feature which more often than not seems to be buggy given that 33k views are on this question already and 52 upvotest as of 2022-01.

```
 SelectField(coerce=int, validate_choice=False)
```

made me a happy camper

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put also the available choices when setting up the Form class.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    sel = SelectField(coerce=int, label="MyLabel", choices=my_choices)
    ....
```

where choices can be something like this:

```
my_choices = [x.id for x in get_products()]
```

The exception is arised in function `pre_validate` in script `/wtforms/fields/core.py` when the `validate_on_submit()` functions is called