# Flask - WTForm - Using Query results as RadioField Choices

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Referencing the following Form.

```
CONTROL_CHOICES = Session.query(schema.OfficeType).order_by(schema.OfficeType.descr).all()
CONTROL_CHOICES = [(office.id, office.descr) for office in CONTROL_CHOICES]

class ControlForm(Form):

    institution = RadioField('Institution', choices=CONTROL_CHOICES)

    date = DateField('Date')
    submit = SubmitField('SUBMIT')
```

### Simple HTML

```
<form action="composition_profile" method="get">
        {{control_form.hidden_tag()}}
        {{control_form.institution.label}}
        {{control_form.institution}}
        {{control_form.date.label}}
        {{control_form.date}}
        {{control_form.submit}}

    </form>
```

The radio fields are successfully printed.[image]

However, when filling out the form, `validate_on_submit()` prints no errors, but does not execute code within the `if`

`validate()` prints the following error.

> {'institution': ['Not a valid choice']}

```
@app.route('/composition_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def composition_profiles():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get('institution') and request.args.get('date'):
            form = ControlForm(request.args)
            print(form.institution.data)

            if form.validate():

                print('terms')
            print(form.errors)
```

Any idea how it is resulting in an improper choice? Im not really sure what's going on. Changing it to `QuerySelectField` works, but I'd like the radio functionality

Comment: What is printed out by the `print(form.institution.data)` statement?

Comment: The description of the radiofield IE `Governor` or `President` It seems switching to `[(office.descr,office.descr) for ....]` is working, but it causes me to requiere an extra join in my query since I have to get back the ID from the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue appears to have been caused due to the fact that WTForm expects the `Value` field, to be a `String` as opposed to an `Integer`

Changing

`CONTROL_CHOICES = [(office.id, office.descr) for office in CONTROL_CHOICES]`

To

`CONTROL_CHOICES = [(str(office.id), office.descr) for office in CONTROL_CHOICES]`

Alleviates the issue

Answer (score 1):

Consider re-factoring:

> ```
> def my_view():
>     class F(MyBaseForm):
>         pass
>
>     F.username = TextField('username')
>     for name in iterate_some_model_dynamically():
>         setattr(F, name, TextField(name.title()))
>
>     form = F(request.POST, ...)
>     # do view stuff
> ```

Source: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition

Comment: This is a nice snippet, thank you, but it seems the direct issue was more result from a direct integer input. I am not sure why it can't handle `1` vs `'1'`

Comment: Try this instead, `institution = RadioField('Institution', choices=CONTROL_CHOICES, coerce=int)`. IMO I think it is better code than wrapping with `str` (If it even works). *Source*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964152/not-a-valid-choice-for-dynamic-select-field-wtforms