# Dynamically Update WTForm with SQL-Alchemy query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to have a form dynamically update by retrieving information from my table then display one of the columns in a SelectField. When I type an asset tag, select a Task Title and hit submit simply nothing happens.

**EDIT: I should add the form is updating fine - all my selections are there and being retrieved successfully. It's simply not executing any of my view function after that.**

My form is as follows;

```
class AssignTasksForm(Form):
    asset_tag = StringField('asset_tag', validators=[DataRequired()])
    task_title = SelectField('task_title', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

My view function;

```
@tasks_blueprint.route('/assign_tasks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def assign_tasks():
    form = AssignTasksForm()
    form.task_title.choices = [(tc.task_id, tc.task_title) for tc in Tasks.query.order_by('task_id')]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                asset_tag = form.asset_tag.data
                asset = Motor.query.filter_by(asset_tag = asset_tag).first_or_404()
                task_title = form.task_title.data
                task = Tasks.query.filter_by(task_title = task_title).first_or_404()
                task.asset_tasks.append(asset)
                db.session.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                flash(e)
                db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('assign_tasks.html', form=form)
```

My terminal output leads me to believe the form may be becoming invalidated after the data is retrieved from the table:

```
2016-08-17 18:21:56,568 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': 1, 'param_1': 1}
2016-08-17 18:21:56,577 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT tasks."Task Title" AS "tasks_Task Title", tasks."Description" AS "tasks_Description", tasks.task_id AS tasks_task_id
FROM tasks ORDER BY tasks.task_id
2016-08-17 18:21:56,577 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
108.168.36.217 - - [17/Aug/2016 18:21:56] "POST /tasks/assign_tasks HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

You can see it run the query outlined in view and then post the webpage but it simply does not continue executing the rest of the view function.

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "basehead.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Assign Tasks Below</h2>
      <br>
      <form action="" method="post" name="submit">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     <p>
        {{ form.asset_tag(placeholder=" Enter Asset Tag") }}
     </p>
     <p>
         {{ form.task_title }}
     </p>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    {% if result_message %}
    <br>
       <p class="result_message"> {{ result_message }} </p>
    </br>
    {% endif %}
    </center>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can print form data after validate_on_submit, see your form content.

Comment: @EmL Okay I added `flash(form.task_title.choices)` after `if request.method == 'POST':` and it successfully flashed all the options it retrieved from the query. So as I suspected something is stopping it from being validated_on_submit.

Comment: Try to set breakpoint at validate_on_submit() function, and debug it. 
Or replace `SelectField ` with `QuerySelectField`, I use `QuerySelectField` when need a dynamically field.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
http://hastebin.com/obojivosar.py

You don't need to check `if request.method == "POST":` I simply moved the populating of the choices to the bottom of the view. I never touch the form before `validate_on_submit` Also how does `result_message` get into the context of the template?

Comment: I didn't think this could be it because as I mentioned it works with just empty fields instead of the drop-down select field. I tried anyways with no luck.  Thank you though.

Comment: I would say then put print statements as soon as you enter the view and then immediately after each if statement. See how far you get.

Comment: The other comment on my original post mentioned that.  I got as far as 'if form.validate_on_submit():` as I had suspected. Something in the validation isn't liking the list the query is returning.

Comment: I tried what you edit in your OP but it did not work because I found the solution for validation. I had to edit my `task_title` object to include `coerce=int` to tell WTForms to handle the `tc.task_id` data as an integer not a string. BUT this led me to another problem I'm getting that deserves it's own post. :( !

Comment: I will, have to wait 2 days it says before you can mark your own comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,

WTForms wants to handle the returned data from the query as a string, however the IDs (integers) obviously are not strings, which must be why validation fails.

By adding `coerce=int` to my `task_title` object in my form definition WTForms now knows to handle it as an int and passes validation.

Fixed code:

```
class AssignTasksForm(Form):
    asset_tag = StringField('asset_tag', validators=[DataRequired()])
    task_title = SelectField('task_title', coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Source: [Not a Valid Choice for Dynamic Select Field WTFORMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964152/not-a-valid-choice-for-dynamic-select-field-wtforms)