# flask wtf-forms SelectField keeps failing

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a function that creates a SelectField selector, but no matter what I do it keeps on failing. I saw several post on similar problems but none was my case.
Here the `forms.py` :

```py
# ...
def select_project( proj_dict ):
    class SelectProject( FlaskForm ):
        new_project_name = SelectField(
            'Select Project',
            choices = list(proj_dict.items()) )
        submit = SubmitField('Change')
    return SelectProject()
# ...
```

and here the `routes.py`:

```py
# ...
from app.forms import select_project

@app.route('/change_project', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def change_project():
    ### prendo una lista di tutti i progetti dell utente
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username).first()
    all_projects = user.projects.all()
    proj_dict = {}
    for p in all_projects :
        proj_dict.update({ p : p })
    form = select_project(proj_dict)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash( form.new_project_name.data )
        proj = Project( name = form.new_project_name.data )
        user.actual_proj = form.new_project_name.data
        proj.last_access = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('project_homepage') )
    return render_template("change_project.html.j2", title='Change Project', form = form )
# ...
```

No matter what I try, it keeps on failing with:

```
 [Not a valid choice]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964152/not-a-valid-choice-for-dynamic-select-field-wtforms). It seems to provide some alternative solutions

Comment: Got it! The problem is that I was importing the list of `projects` as a list of class `Project` elements, just changed it to
```python
    for p in all_projects :
        proj_dict.update({ str(p) : str(p) })
```
solved the problem! Thank you very much, I did not found that post!