# WTF.forms "Not a Valid Choice" error for SelectField dynamically updated

Tags: javascript, python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I saw some similar question about this one but none of them had a clear answer. So I will try to make it clear as possible.

I initially posted the question with peace of my real code which was not easy for someone to replicate as it depend on connection to Oracle Database connection. So I did a simplified version of it.

So. First Things First. What I am doing is to creat a form with 4 SelectField using Flask. The choices for the first SelectField is defined in the class definition (in the view part). The choices of the other 3 SelecteFields are dynamically defined based on the choices of the previous fields.

The problem is that when I submit the form I receive a "Not a valid choice" for these 3 fields.

I followed this tutorial to create this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2dJuNwlIH0

The view (form_toy.py) code is the following

```
from flask import Flask,session,request,render_template,jsonify,url_for,redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='asdas8789)(&673'
bootstrap=Bootstrap(app)

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    
    df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
    df1=df['site'].drop_duplicates()
    choices_site=[]
    i=1
    for _,v in df1.iteritems(): 
        choices_site.append((i,v)) 
        i=i+1
    
    site = SelectField("Site",coerce=int,choices=choices_site)
    plant = SelectField("Plant",coerce=int,choices=[])
    ctrl = SelectField("Ctrl",coerce=int,choices=[])
    subctrl = SelectField("Sub",coerce=int,choices=[])
    submit = SubmitField("OK")

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    site = ''
    plant = ''
    ctrl = ''
    subctrl = ''
    form =TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        site = form.site.data
        plant = form.plant.data
        ctrl = form.ctrl.data
        subctrl = form.subctrl.data
    
    return render_template('index.html',
                           form=form,
                           site=site,
                           plant=plant,
                           ctrl=ctrl,
                           subctrl=subctrl)

@app.route("/plant/<site>")
def GetPlant(site):
    plants_array = []
    df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
    df1=df.loc[df['site']==site]
    df2=df1['plant'].drop_duplicates()
    
    i=1
    for _,p in df2.iteritems():
        plants_array.append({'id':i,'plant':p})
        i=i+1

    return jsonify({'plants':plants_array})

@app.route("/ctrl/<site>/<plant>")
def GetCtrl(site,plant):
    ctrls_array = []
    df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
    df1=df.loc[df['site']==site]
    df2=df1.loc[df1['plant']==plant]
    df3=df2['ctrl'].drop_duplicates()
    
    i=1
    for _,c in df3.iteritems():
        ctrls_array.append({'id':i,'ctrl':c})
        i=i+1

    return jsonify({'ctrls':ctrls_array})

@app.route("/subctrl/<site>/<plant>/<ctrl>")
def GetSubCtrl(site,plant,ctrl):
    subctrls_array = []
    df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
    df1=df.loc[df['site']==site]
    df2=df1.loc[df1['plant']==plant]
    df3=df2.loc[df2['ctrl']==ctrl]
    df4=df3['subctrl'].drop_duplicates()
    
    i=1
    for _,s in df4.iteritems():
        subctrls_array.append({'id':i,'subctrl':s})
        i=i+1

    return jsonify({'subctrls':subctrls_array})
```

The template code (index.html) is here (I put everything in the same file for the sake of simplification)

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}FORM_VALIDATION{% endblock %}

{{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors}}
{% endif %}

<script>
    var site_select = document.getElementById("site");
    var plant_select = document.getElementById("plant");
    var ctrl_select = document.getElementById("ctrl");
    var subctrl_select = document.getElementById("subctrl")
    var plant1=''
    var ctrl1 = ''

    site_select.onchange = function(){
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        get_options_plants(site);
    };

    plant_select.onchange = function(){
        // get controllers
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var plant = plant_select.options[plant_select.selectedIndex].text;
        get_options_ctrl(site,plant)
    };

    ctrl_select.onchange = function(){
        //get subctrollers
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var plant = plant_select.options[plant_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var ctrl = ctrl_select.options[ctrl_select.selectedIndex].text;
        get_options_subctrl(site,plant,ctrl)
    };

    function get_options_plants(site){
        //get plant;
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        fetch('plant/'+site).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
               
                for (var plant of data.plants){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(plant.id) + '>' + plant.plant + '</option>'
                    if (plant1==''){
                        plant1=plant.plant
                    }
                }
                plant_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                get_options_ctrl(plant1)                 
            })       
        
        });
    };

    function get_options_ctrl(site,plant){
        //get controllers
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var plant = plant_select.options[plant_select.selectedIndex].text;
        fetch('ctrl/'+site+'/'+plant).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
                for (var ctrl of data.ctrls){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(ctrl.id) + '>' + ctrl.ctrl + '</option>'
                    if (ctrl1==''){
                        ctrl1=ctrl.ctrl
                    }
                }
                ctrl_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                get_options_subctrl(site,ctrl1)
            })
        });
        plant1='';
    }

    function get_options_subctrl(site,plant,ctrl){
        //get subcontrollers
        var site = site_select.options[site_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var plant = plant_select.options[plant_select.selectedIndex].text;
        var ctrl = ctrl_select.options[ctrl_select.selectedIndex].text;

        fetch('subctrl/'+site+'/'+plant+'/'+ctrl).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
                for (var sub of data.subctrls){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(sub.id) + '>' + sub.subctrl + '</option>'
                }
                subctrl_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
            })
        });
        ctrl1='';
    }

    //call get_option_plants() to initiate menus
    get_options_plants();
</script>
```

and finally the data to populate the fields are stored in a csv file (db.csv) which is read using pandas.

```
site,plant,ctrl,subctrl
s1,p11,c111,s1a
s1,p11,c111,s2b
s1,p11,c111,s3c
s1,p11,c211,s1d
s1,p11,c211,s2e
s1,p21,c121,s1f
s1,p21,c121,s2g
s1,p21,c221,s1h
s1,p21,c221,s2i
s1,p21,c221,s3j
s2,p12,c112,s1k
s2,p12,c112,s2l
s2,p12,c112,s3m
s2,p12,c222,s1n
s2,p12,c222,s2o
s2,p22,c122,s1p
s2,p22,c122,s2q
s2,p22,c222,s1r
s2,p22,c222,s2s
s2,p22,c222,s3t
```

I would apreciate any help as I am pretty new on this field of web app.

I have found some post related to the problem like this one.

[Not a Valid Choice for Dynamic Select Field WTFORMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964152/not-a-valid-choice-for-dynamic-select-field-wtforms)

But I follow the instruction but it didn't solved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out what is the problem. In the view (backend) I need on initalize the argument choice with all possible options which I can have in each field. I realized that by reading this link

https://coderedirect.com/questions/192536/populate-wtforms-select-field-using-value-selected-from-previous-field

Doing so. I can use the JS code to show to the user just the values necessary according to the values selected in the previous fields.

So. For whoever may be interested this are the updated version of the code. It is not the most eficient way to implement it (I guess) but it works to show how it works.

```
from flask import Flask,session,request,render_template,jsonify,url_for,redirect,g
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='asdas8789)(&673'
bootstrap=Bootstrap(app)

class FormChoices():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.choices_site={}
        self.choices_plant={}
        self.choices_ctrl={}
        self.choices_subctrl={}
        n=0 #site
        i=0 #plant
        j=0 #ctrl
        k=0 #subctrl
        df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
        df1=df['site'].drop_duplicates() 
        for _,s in df1.iteritems():
            self.choices_site[n]=s
            df2=df.loc[df['site']==s]
            df3=df2['plant'].drop_duplicates()
            
            self.choices_plant[n]={}
            self.choices_ctrl[n]={}
            self.choices_subctrl[n]={}
            
            for _,p in df3.iteritems():
                self.choices_plant[n][i]=p
                
                df4=df.loc[df['site']==s]
                df5=df4.loc[df4['plant']==p]
                df6=df5['ctrl'].drop_duplicates()
                
                self.choices_ctrl[n][i]={}
                self.choices_subctrl[n][i]={}
                
                for _,c in df6.iteritems():
                    self.choices_ctrl[n][i][j]=c
                    
                    df7=df.loc[df['site']==s]
                    df8=df7.loc[df7['plant']==p]
                    df9=df8.loc[df8['ctrl']==c]
                    df10=df9['subctrl'].drop_duplicates()
                    
                    self.choices_subctrl[n][i][j]={}
                    
                    for _,sub in df10.iteritems():
                        self.choices_subctrl[n][i][j][k]=sub
                        k=k+1
                    j=j+1
                i=i+1
            n=n+1
        
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    
    df=pd.read_csv('db.csv')
    df1=df['site'].drop_duplicates()
    choices_site=[]
    choices_plant=[]
    choices_ctrl=[]
    choices_subctrl=[]

    formc = FormChoices()
    for k0,v0 in formc.choices_site.items():
        choices_site.append((k0,v0))
        for k1,v1 in formc.choices_plant[k0].items():
            choices_plant.append((k1,v1))
            for k2,v2 in formc.choices_ctrl[k0][k1].items():
                choices_ctrl.append((k2,v2))
                for k3,v3 in formc.choices_subctrl[k0][k1][k2].items():
                    choices_subctrl.append((k3,v3))
    
    site = SelectField("Site",coerce=int,choices=choices_site)
    plant = SelectField("Plant",coerce=int,choices=choices_plant)
    ctrl = SelectField("Ctrl",coerce=int,choices=choices_ctrl)
    subctrl = SelectField("Sub",coerce=int,choices=choices_subctrl)
    submit = SubmitField("OK")

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    site = ''
    plant = ''
    ctrl = ''
    subctrl = ''
    x = None
    g.form = TestForm()
    if g.form.validate_on_submit(): #request.method=='POST':
        site = g.form.site.data
        plant = g.form.plant.data
        ctrl = g.form.ctrl.data
        subctrl = g.form.subctrl.data
        ch=FormChoices()
        x=ch.choices_ctrl[plant][ctrl]

        return render_template('test.html',
                               x=plant,
                               y=ctrl,
                               z=subctrl)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html',
                            form=g.form,
                            site=site,
                            plant=plant,
                            ctrl=ctrl,
                            subctrl=subctrl,
                            x=plant,
                            y=ctrl,
                            z=subctrl)

@app.route("/plant/<site_id>")
def GetPlant(site_id):
    plants_array = []

    ch=FormChoices()
    
    for k,v in ch.choices_plant[int(site_id)].items():
        plants_array.append({'id':k,'plant':v})
        
    return jsonify({'plants':plants_array})

@app.route("/ctrl/<site_id>/<plant_id>")
def GetCtrl(site_id,plant_id):
    ctrls_array = []
    
    ch=FormChoices()
    for k,v in ch.choices_ctrl[int(site_id)][int(plant_id)].items():
        ctrls_array.append({'id':k,'ctrl':v})
        
    return jsonify({'ctrls':ctrls_array})

@app.route("/subctrl/<site_id>/<plant_id>/<ctrl_id>")
def GetSubCtrl(site_id,plant_id,ctrl_id):
    subctrls_array = []
    
    ch=FormChoices()
    for k,v in ch.choices_subctrl[int(site_id)][int(plant_id)][int(ctrl_id)].items():
        subctrls_array.append({'id':k,'subctrl':v})

    return jsonify({'subctrls':subctrls_array})
```

here is the html

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}FORM_VALIDATION{% endblock %}

{{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors}}
{% endif %}
<h2>{{x}},{{y}},{{z}}</h2>

<script>
    var site_select = document.getElementById("site");
    var plant_select = document.getElementById("plant");
    var ctrl_select = document.getElementById("ctrl");
    var subctrl_select = document.getElementById("subctrl")
    var plant1 = ''
    var ctrl1 = ''

    site_select.onchange = function(){
        var site_id = site_select.value;
        get_options_plants(site_id);
    };

    plant_select.onchange = function(){
        // get controllers
        var site_id = site_select.value
        var plant_id = plant_select.value;
        get_options_ctrl(site_id,plant_id)
    };

    ctrl_select.onchange = function(){
        //get subctrollers
        var site_id = site_select.value
        var plant_id = plant_select.value;
        var ctrl_id = ctrl_select.value;
        get_options_subctrl(site_id,plant_id,ctrl_id)
    };

    function get_options_plants(site){
        //get plant;
        var site_id = site_select.value;
        fetch('plant/'+site_id).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
               
                for (var plant of data.plants){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(plant.id) + '>' + plant.plant + '</option>'
                    if (plant1==''){
                        plant1=plant.plant
                    }
                }
                plant_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                get_options_ctrl(plant1)                 
            })       
        
        });
    };

    function get_options_ctrl(site,plant){
        //get controllers
        var site_id = site_select.value
        var plant_id = plant_select.value;
        fetch('ctrl/'+site_id+'/'+plant_id).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
                for (var ctrl of data.ctrls){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(ctrl.id) + '>' + ctrl.ctrl + '</option>'
                    if (ctrl1==''){
                        ctrl1=ctrl.ctrl
                    }
                }
                ctrl_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
                get_options_subctrl(site,ctrl1)
            })
        });
        plant1='';
    }

    function get_options_subctrl(site,plant,ctrl){
        //get subcontrollers
        var site_id = site_select.value
        var plant_id = plant_select.value;
        var ctrl_id = ctrl_select.value;

        fetch('subctrl/'+site_id+'/'+plant_id+'/'+ctrl_id).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(data){
                var optionHTML='';
                for (var sub of data.subctrls){
                    optionHTML += '<option value=' + parseInt(sub.id) + '>' + sub.subctrl + '</option>'
                }
                subctrl_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
            })
        });
        ctrl1='';
    }

    //call get_option_plants() to initiate menus
    get_options_plants();
</script>
```

and here another html that I used for test.

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}FORM_VALIDATION{% endblock %}

<h2>{{x}},{{y}},{{z}}</h2>
```

Hope this can be usefull to someone.